# How do I simulate the collar?

Tags: cloth-simulation

T-shirts can be simulated,
How do I simulate clothes with stiff collars?
I don't think there's any change even if I control the property weight.
Please tell me how to make the caragit stiff in Marblus designer.

Comment: The pin group is fixed, so the simulation doesn't apply. I want my clothes to move according to how they move. I want it to be stiff. If the blender is simulating the clothes slipping off, The pin group doesn't slide down from the spot.